# Is it possible to layer other Xamarin.Forms controls over WebView on iOS and/or Android?

Tags: android, ios, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm assuming that the Xamarin.Forms WebView implementation on both iOS and Android would use the "native" browser for each platform.

Does that enable other Xamarin.Forms controls to be layered over the top if it?

I am not sure because I have used other toolkits which use "lightweight" controls on each platform and thus cannot be layered over a "heavyweight" control but I also believe Xamarin.Forms uses all native components on each platform (thus potentially making this possible).

Could someone please clarify for me?

Thanks!

Comment: By on top of it do you mean that you want your widget/control to float over the WebView something like how a floating action button works?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I may need to overlay some components over the WebView (hopefully translucently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible, even though it is not a good idea to cover any part of the webview control for obvious reasons.

```
            <Grid> 
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="redball.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" 
                       VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                <Frame x:Name="frmFooter" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
```

This sample places a tiny **red ball** on the top-center of your webview control.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I consider the question answered.